# Finding words from a hash using regular expressions in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm doing the [Test-First Learn Ruby](https://github.com/alexch/learn_ruby) questions and for the Dictionary question it is asking that a define a method "find" that takes a string as a parameter to search against the keys of a hash containing words and return the key value pairs there the string matches the key. It has to satisfy these situations:

```
it 'finds multiple matches from a prefix and returns the entire entry (keyword + definition)' do
  @d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')
  @d.add('fiend' => 'wicked person')
  @d.add('great' => 'remarkable')
  @d.find('fi').should == {'fish' => 'aquatic animal', 'fiend' => 'wicked person'}
end
```

My knowledge of regular expressions isn't great. I am at a bit of a loss of what to do here. Help?  I think I can pretty well get it to return the key values pairs given that the string an key matches completely, but for this partial matching I am perplexed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you actually need to use regexp here. The test implies that the method will get a string and check it against the hash keys' *prefixes*. This could be achieved by:

```
def find(string)
  hash.select { |key, value| key.start_with?(string) }
end
```

Also, [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com) might be a good resource to learn and test regexp

Comment: To follow up with this answer, check out the [official Ruby Docs to learn more about Hashes](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html).

Comment: Thanks, oddly enough I did stumble upon Rubular as I was trying to work this out I did eventually work it out with a regular expression hash.has_key?(/^#{string}.*/)